# How to create structures in mex files?

Tags: matlab, struct, mex

I have this C structure:

```
struct position
{
    float x, y, z;
};

struct orientation
{
    float x, y, z;
};

struct robot
{
    position pose;
    orientation or;
};
```

And in the main I just use

> struct robot data

The question is how do I create that structure in a mex function? 
Thanks

EDIT 1:
What I want to achieve in the .mat file is this:

```
robot <1x5 struct>
  robot(1,1) <1x1 struct>
     robot(1,1).position <1x1 struct> 
        x
        y
        z
     robot(1,1).orientation <1x1 struct> with x,y and z fields
        x
        y
        z
  robot(1,2) <1x1 struct>
     robot(1,2).position <1x1 struct> with x,y and z fields
        x
        y
        z
     robot(1,2).orientation <1x1 struct> with x,y and z fields
        x
        y
        z
                  .
                  .
                  .
  robot(1,5) <1x1 struct>
     robot(1,5).position <1x1 struct> with x,y and z fields
        x
        y
        z
     robot(1,5).orientation <1x1 struct> with x,y and z fields
        x
        y
        z
```

I was able get the structure that I need:

```
double values[5] = {1,2,3,4}; //Just for testing.
const char *field_robot[] = {"pos", "or"};
const char *field_coordinates[] = {"x", "y", "z"};
mxPos = mxCreateStructMatrix(1,1,3, field_coordinates);
mxOr = mxCreateStructMatrix(1,1,3, field_coordinates);
mxRobot = mxCreateStructMatrix(1,1,5, field_robot);

for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    mxSetFieldByNumber(mxPos, 0, 0, mxCreateDoubleScalar(values[i]));
    mxSetFieldByNumber(mxRobot, i, 0, mxPos);
}
```

I can see in matlab it is how I want, but inside robot.pos.x I only have 4 for all the values. It is only saving the last value.

Comment: Do you want to pass the structure back to Matlab? Or do you just want to use it these structures in an intermediary step of some function call?

Comment: I want to use these structures in an intermediary step. I want to use the MAT-File API functions to store the 'mex' variables in a .mat file. Declaring `MATFile *pmat` and `mxArray *pa` then you call `memcpy((void *)(mxGetPr(pa)), (void *)data, sizeof(data))` and after `matPutVariable(pmat, "LocalDouble", pa)`.

Answer (score 1):

The code below is from the MATLAB built-in example "phonebook.c" and shows an example of how to create a MATLAB struct array in a MeX file.  You can view the entire source file in MATLAB with the command:

```
edit([matlabroot '/extern/examples/refbook/phonebook.c']);
```

You can find online documentation at the mathworks site:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/passing-structures-and-cell-arrays.html?refresh=true#zmw57dd0e20943

```
const char **fnames;       /* pointers to field names */
const mwSize *dims;
mxArray    *tmp, *fout;
char       *pdata=NULL;
int        ifield, nfields;
mxClassID  *classIDflags;
mwIndex    jstruct;
mwSize     NStructElems;
mwSize     ndim;

/* allocate memory  for storing pointers */
fnames = mxCalloc(nfields, sizeof(*fnames));
/* get field name pointers */
for (ifield=0; ifield< nfields; ifield++){
    fnames[ifield] = mxGetFieldNameByNumber(prhs[0],ifield);
}
/* create a 1x1 struct matrix for output  */
plhs[0] = mxCreateStructMatrix(1, 1, nfields, fnames);
mxFree((void *)fnames);
ndim = mxGetNumberOfDimensions(prhs[0]);
dims = mxGetDimensions(prhs[0]);
for(ifield=0; ifield<nfields; ifield++) {
    /* create cell/numeric array */
    if(classIDflags[ifield] == mxCHAR_CLASS) {
        fout = mxCreateCellArray(ndim, dims);
    }else {
        fout = mxCreateNumericArray(ndim, dims, classIDflags[ifield], mxREAL);
        pdata = mxGetData(fout);
    }
    /* copy data from input structure array */
    for (jstruct=0; jstruct<NStructElems; jstruct++) {
        tmp = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0],jstruct,ifield);
        if( mxIsChar(tmp)) {
            mxSetCell(fout, jstruct, mxDuplicateArray(tmp));
        }else {
            mwSize     sizebuf;
            sizebuf = mxGetElementSize(tmp);
            memcpy(pdata, mxGetData(tmp), sizebuf);
            pdata += sizebuf;
        }
    }
    /* set each field in output structure */
    mxSetFieldByNumber(plhs[0], 0, ifield, fout);
}
mxFree(classIDflags);
```

Comment: I found that and I was able to create the 'first' 1x1 struct "robot", but now I have to create two new structures within "robot", "position" and "orientation" which are also structures......that's the issue I'm facing.

Comment: Should I rather save it in a binary file and the load it in matlab? Will it have the nested structures?